# Python executable - creating directories and file access

Tags: python, file, directory, operating-system, executable

I have created a simple Python script **test.py** that is supposed to check if a directory exists, and, if it does not, to create it.

The code is as follows:

```
import os

    def crete_dir(dir_name):
        if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
            os.makedirs(dir_name)
    
    crete_dir("test_dir")
```

I am on Mac and use PyCharm to write and test my code.

The script works as expected so long as I run it in PyCharm, but as soon as I turn it into an executable (using pyinstaller: *pyinstaller --onefile --clean --windowed test.py*) and run it, it does not work (does not create the directory, even though it does not exist). The terminal window, that opens alongside the executable, does not return any file-access-permission or other error.

What should I please do to make the executable work normally?
Many thanks.

Comment: Try running the exe file with administrator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @IsmailHafeez. I tried navigating to the executable's directory: and entering "sudo test" and also "chmod +rwx test", but to no avail.